# Matching color game in C#

Tags: c#

I need to create a memory game matching pairs of colors in C#
I have a List object with the colors already defined. I have a function called AssignColorsToSquares() where I assign the colors to the .BackColor property of each label. But I want to know how can I run the app with all the labels set up with a default .Backcolor, so in that way the user does not know which color is... Here is the code:

```
  List<Color> colores = new List<Color>() 
    {
       Color.Green, Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Yellow, Color.Fuchsia, Color.Fuchsia,Color.Blue, Color.Blue, Color.Beige, Color.Beige, Color.Pink, Color.Pink, Color.Violet, Color.Violet
    };

    /// <summary> 
    /// Assign each icon from the list of icons to a random square 
    /// </summary> 
    private void AssignColorsToSquares()
    {
        // The TableLayoutPanel has 16 labels, 
        // and the icon list has 16 icons, 
        // so an icon is pulled at random from the list 
        // and added to each label.
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            Label colorLabel = control as Label;
            if (colorLabel != null)
            {
                int randomNumber = random.Next(colores.Count);
                colorLabel.BackColor = colores[randomNumber];
                colorLabel.ForeColor = colorLabel.BackColor;
                colores.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    } 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AssignIconsToSquares();
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Every label's Click event is handled by this event handler.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="sender">The label that was clicked.</param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The timer is only on after two non-matching  
        // icons have been shown to the player,  
        // so ignore any clicks if the timer is running 
        if (timer1.Enabled == true)
            return; 

        Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;

        if (clickedLabel != null)
        {
            // If the clicked label is black, the player clicked 
            // an icon that's already been revealed -- 
            // ignore the click.
            if (clickedLabel.ForeColor == Color.Black)
                // All done - leave the if statements.
                return;

            // If firstClicked is null, this is the first icon  
            // in the pair that the player clicked, 
            // so set firstClicked to the label that the player  
            // clicked, change its color to black, and return. 
            if (firstClicked == null)
            {
                firstClicked = clickedLabel;
                firstClicked.ForeColor = Color.Black;

                // All done - leave the if statements.
                return;
            }

            // If the player gets this far, the timer isn't 
            // running and firstClicked isn't null, 
            // so this must be the second icon the player clicked 
            // Set its color to black.
            secondClicked = clickedLabel;
            secondClicked.ForeColor = Color.Black;

            // Check to see if the player won.
            CheckForWinner();

            // If the player clicked two matching icons, keep them  
            // black and reset firstClicked and secondClicked  
            // so the player can click another icon. 
            if (firstClicked.BackColor == secondClicked.BackColor)
            {
                firstClicked = null;
                secondClicked = null;
                return;
            }

            // If the player gets this far, the player  
            // clicked two different icons, so start the  
            // timer (which will wait three quarters of  
            // a second, and then hide the icons).
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// This timer is started when the player clicks  
    /// two icons that don't match, 
    /// so it counts three quarters of a second  
    /// and then turns itself off and hides both icons.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the timer.
        timer1.Stop();

        // Hide both icons.
        firstClicked.ForeColor = firstClicked.BackColor;
        secondClicked.ForeColor = secondClicked.BackColor;

        // Reset firstClicked and secondClicked  
        // so the next time a label is 
        // clicked, the program knows it's the first click.
        firstClicked = null;
        secondClicked = null;
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Check every icon to see if it is matched, by  
    /// comparing its foreground color to its background color.  
    /// If all of the icons are matched, the player wins. 
    /// </summary> 
    private void CheckForWinner()
    {
        // Go through all of the labels in the TableLayoutPanel,  
        // checking each one to see if its icon is matched.
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            Label colorLabel = control as Label;

            if (colorLabel != null)
            {
                if (colorLabel.ForeColor == colorLabel.BackColor)
                    return;
            }
        }

        // If the loop didn’t return, it didn't find 
        // any unmatched icons. 
        // That means the user won. Show a message and close the form.
        MessageBox.Show("You matched all the icons!", "Congratulations!");
        Close();
    }
```

}

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: that in my code it shows me the colors on the labels when the app starts and it should not show the colors... do you want me to upload the code completely so you can see the form as well... ?

Comment: You should always provide a [mcve] whenever possible.

Comment: got it! I will update the post.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have edited the main post. Thanks!

Comment: Question should [include relevant code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed), otherwise question is likely to be closed as *"Unclear"*.

Comment: I edited the post again.. tell me if it is enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted.
here is the code:

```
 private void AssignarColoresAEtiquetas()
    {
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            Label colorLabel = control as Label;

            if (colorLabel != null)
            {                    
                    int randomNumber = random.Next(colores.Count);
                    colorLabel.BackColor = colores[randomNumber];
                    colorLabel.ForeColor = colorLabel.BackColor;
                    colorLabel.Image = Properties.Resources.Captura1;
                    colores.RemoveAt(randomNumber);                                   
            }
        }
    }
```

I set also an image to the labels so it can cover the backcolor of the labels. In that way, the labels appears covered with a default image.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your best to separate the view and logic behind your matching game. That being said the following uses a Dictionary for the logic. The game works so when one clicks on two unmatching colors they will turn back to cornflower blue after timer completes. Select two matching and they will not revert back to cornflower blue. Once all are selected your message Congratulations! appears.

```
    /// <summary> 
    /// Assign each icon from the list of icons to a random square 
    /// </summary> 
    Dictionary<Label, Color> labelToColor = new Dictionary<Label, Color>();
    private void AssignIconsToSquares()
    {
        // The TableLayoutPanel has 16 labels, 
        // and the icon list has 16 icons, 
        // so an icon is pulled at random from the list 
        // and added to each label.
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            Label colorLabel = control as Label;
            if (colorLabel != null)
            {
                int randomNumber = random.Next(colores.Count);
                labelToColor.Add(colorLabel, colores[randomNumber]);

                //colorLabel.BackColor = colores[randomNumber];
                colorLabel.ForeColor = colorLabel.BackColor;
                colores.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AssignIconsToSquares();
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Every label's Click event is handled by this event handler.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="sender">The label that was clicked.</param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The timer is only on after two non-matching  
        // icons have been shown to the player,  
        // so ignore any clicks if the timer is running 
        if (timer1.Enabled == true)
            return;

        Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;

        if (clickedLabel != null)
        {
            // If the clicked label is black, the player clicked 
            // an icon that's already been revealed -- 
            // ignore the click.
            if (clickedLabel.ForeColor == Color.Black)
                // All done - leave the if statements.
                return;

            // If firstClicked is null, this is the first icon  
            // in the pair that the player clicked, 
            // so set firstClicked to the label that the player  
            // clicked, change its color to black, and return. 
            if (firstClicked == null)
            {
                firstClicked = clickedLabel;
                firstClicked.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                firstClicked.BackColor = labelToColor[firstClicked];

                // All done - leave the if statements.
                return;
            }

            // If the player gets this far, the timer isn't 
            // running and firstClicked isn't null, 
            // so this must be the second icon the player clicked 
            // Set its color to black.
            secondClicked = clickedLabel;
            secondClicked.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            secondClicked.BackColor = labelToColor[secondClicked];

            // Check to see if the player won.
            CheckForWinner();

            // If the player clicked two matching icons, keep them  
            // black and reset firstClicked and secondClicked  
            // so the player can click another icon. 
            Color firstColor = labelToColor[secondClicked];
            if (labelToColor[firstClicked] == labelToColor[secondClicked])
            {
                firstClicked = null;
                secondClicked = null;
                return;
            }


            // If the player gets this far, the player  
            // clicked two different icons, so start the  
            // timer (which will wait three quarters of  
            // a second, and then hide the icons).
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// This timer is started when the player clicks  
    /// two icons that don't match, 
    /// so it counts three quarters of a second  
    /// and then turns itself off and hides both icons.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the timer.
        timer1.Stop();

        // Hide both icons.
        firstClicked.ForeColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        secondClicked.ForeColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;

        firstClicked.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        secondClicked.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        // Reset firstClicked and secondClicked  
        // so the next time a label is 
        // clicked, the program knows it's the first click.
        firstClicked = null;
        secondClicked = null;
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Check every icon to see if it is matched, by  
    /// comparing its foreground color to its background color.  
    /// If all of the icons are matched, the player wins. 
    /// </summary> 
    private void CheckForWinner()
    {
        // Go through all of the labels in the TableLayoutPanel,  
        // checking each one to see if its icon is matched.
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            Label colorLabel = control as Label;

            if (colorLabel != null)
            {
                if (colorLabel.ForeColor == colorLabel.BackColor)
                    return;
            }
        }

        // If the loop didn’t return, it didn't find 
        // any unmatched icons. 
        // That means the user won. Show a message and close the form.
        MessageBox.Show("You matched all the icons!", "Congratulations!");
        Close();
    }
```